# Is a dead thread a threat to memory leak?

Tags: java, multithreading

Is a dead thread a threat to memory usage? Will it eventually get collected by the GC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A dead thread, as any other object, will be collected by the GC if cannot be reached by any references to it. Setting **ALL** variables that point to it to `null` should make it available for collection by the GC.

A threat to memory usage ... it depends on how much memory you're using in it - and how many references to other object instances (Lists, Hashtables, ...). It's exactly the same threat to memory usage as any other type of object.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously if your code still has a reference the thread object is still there, you can't restart it but its still a usable java object (sorry if that was too obvious, best to eliminate that first ;-) )

The same discussion has happened over here .

http://www.coderanch.com/t/531074/threads/java/dead-thread-threat-memory-leak

Answer (score 1):

Setting the thread object to null should guarantee GC on the dead thread object.

Answer (score 1):

Just put all resources you don't use anymore to rest by it putting it to `null` better safe then sorry. GC will pick that up.